# ros_java build failing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have been trying to get rosjava working but I am facing problems :). After I download rosjava and try to install it with

./gradlew build

I get the one failed test

Test org.ros.time.NtpTimeProviderTest FAILED

and eventually the build fails. What am I doing wrong?
Does any one have any idea how I can resolve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54853/ros_java-build-failing/) by [mfahad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4172/mfahad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That test is flaky and you can avoid running it using `-x test`. Really you should be calling the `install` task though which will copy the artifacts to your m2 cache so they can be used. The `install` task does not run the tests.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0